# Unable to push formdata in Array of Object using Angular4

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have form it is placed in Bootstrap model and when user click on submit button i want push the form data in `TaskList` .

But when user click on submit button in form the  formdata is not push to `TaskList` and is redirected to another page like [Link](http://localhost:3000/?taskname=&description=&duedate=) and ngSubmit also not working.

If i remove the "TaskList" push code in type script file, the form  `ngSubmit` is working fine and i got form data and both case i am not getting any errors.

how to get the data from my form and push in to `TaskList` array ob object.

**TS:**

```
export class TodoListComponent  { 

    TaskList : Task[];
     name:string;
    onAddtask(form : NgForm){
        console.log(form);
        this.TaskList.push({
            id:this.TaskList.length+1,
            title:form.value.taskname,
            description:form.value.description,
            due:form.value.duedate,
            done:false
        });
    }

}


interface Task {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    description?: string,
    due?: string,
    done: boolean
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="well well-sm">
                <h1>Todos</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addTaskModel">+ Add</button>
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="addTaskModel" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form (ngSubmit)="onAddtask(addtask.value)" #addtask="ngForm">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="taskname">Task Name:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="taskname" name="taskname" ngModel>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="description">Task Description</label>
                                        <textarea col="6" rows="6" class="form-control" name="description" ngModel></textarea>
                                                       </div>
                                                       <div class="form-group">
                                                               <label for="duedate">Due Date</label>
                                                               <input class="form-control" type="date" name="duedate" ngModel>
                                                             </div>
                                               <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Clear</button>
                                               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                               </form> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- Model End Here-->
            </div>
```

Comment: try `$event.preventDefault()` with submit to prevent the native behavior of submit button?

Comment: description?: string,
    due?: string,

Are these questions markes required?


Try  TaskList : [],  without interface and see if it works.  

Redirects happens because somewhere javascript error destroy built in preventDefault

Comment: Not relevant: be careful with   id:this.TaskList.length+1

Comment: @AJT_82 : if i remove push code from ngsubmit function is not redirect and i got form data . and when we add the push code in ngsubmit function is not working fine

Comment: @CodeMan Yes, well have you tried event.preventDefault() ?

Comment: @AJT_82 : i tried to remove interface reference it working fine.